# Reducing objects properties to get new object

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I have,

```
var oldUsers = [{
    "SID": "S-12",
        "Username": "bring.on",
        "firstname": "bring",
        "lastname": "on",
        "email": "emasdklhsjas@gmnailasd.com"
    // and so on... 10 more properties
}, {
    "SID": "S-13",
        "Username": "bring.on1",
        "firstname": "bring",
        "lastname": "on1",
        "email": "sdf@gmnailasd.com"
    // and so on... 10 more properties
},
              // n numbers of more users...];
```

What I want,

```
var newUsers = [{ FullName : "bring on - emasdklhsjas@gmnailasd.com",
                 value : S-12
               },
              { FullName : "bring on1 - sdf@gmnailasd.com",
                 value : S-13
               }, // more users with same properties as abvove
              ];
```

What I tried but failed,

```
var newUsers = $.each(oldUser, function () {
    return u = {
        value : this.SID,
        FullName : this.firstname + " " + this.lastname + " - " + this.email,
    };
});
```

It needs to work on IE-8+ not sure what I am doing wrong really.

All I want is to reduce properties of object in array and get a new object.

Comment: `$.each` ignores the result (aside from stopping iteration on `false`). Use `$.map` instead, or explicitly collect results into an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var newUsers = [];
$.each(oldUser, function () {
    newUsers.push({
        value : this.SID,
        FullName : this.firstname + " " + this.lastname + " - " + this.email,
    });
});
```

[Here is a fiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/sx5udjLa/). Check your console log for the outcome when you run the fiddle.

Answer (score 3):

[`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can be used to create new array using Plain old Vanilla JavaScript.

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array

```
var newUsers = oldUser.map(function(obj){
    return {
        value : obj.SID,
        FullName : obj.firstname + " " + obj.lastname + " - " + obj.email,
    }
});
```

Note: It will work with IE9+

Using [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)

```
var newUsers = jQuery.map(oldUser, function(obj){
    return {
        value : obj.SID,
        FullName : obj.firstname + " " + obj.lastname + " - " + obj.email,
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `.each` function doesn't return anything. 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/.  It iterates over the collection of objects and performs and action on each one.  This is different than the functional concept of the higher order function map, which is used to translate one collection into another.  (JQuery has a map function [too](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/).)

To fix your problem you either need to do:

```
var newArray = []
var newUsers = $.each(oldUser, function () {
    newArray.push ({
        value : this.SID,
        FullName : this.firstname + " " + this.lastname + " - " + this.email,
    });
});

or 

  var newArray = $.map(oldUsers, function (u,i) {
    return {
        value : this.SID,
        FullName : u.firstname + " " + u.lastname + " - " + u.email,
    };
});
```

Personally, I would go with the second one, as it reduces the number of [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) in your code.

Edit: Apparently, map does not work in IE 8, so the top one is the more correct approach.

Comment: Why did you posted almost identical answers?

Answer (score 0):

try this!

```
var newArr= [];
$.each(users, function (index , user) {
    newArr.push({
       value : user.SID,
       FullName : user.firstname + " " + user.lastname + " - " + user.email,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object is an array of objects, so make use of Array map method:
`var result = oldUsers.map(function(e){
    return { Fullname : e.firstname + e.lastname, value : e['SID']};
});`